# Why does the new style user page not show gravatars properly?

Tags: bug

I'm finding that the new style Users page does not seem to be showing gravatars properly. Mine shows fine in questions and in my profile, but is some weird brown geometry on the users pages.

Apparently, I'm not alone in this since quite a few other users are also getting default gravatar rendering.

Any particular reason for this?

Other than that, I like the concept of the new Users page, it seems to reduce the rep competition by relegating all time top scores to a much less prominent location with emphasis on recent gainers. This encourages continuous engagement.

**Update**

This doesn't seem to happen on my home machine (Macbook Pro with Chrome), but is happening at work (XP with FF3). Here's a screenshot (from Users | All) to illustrate:

[image: Screen shot from Users | All]

**Update 2**

The gravatar URI for Jeff O (one of the few currently still showing as a default) is "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/970d11475b62705c41719801b176bf2a?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG".

Mine seems to have returned to normal.

Comment: er.. what? can you include a screenshot? what browser and OS?

Comment: @Jeff Hmm, seems to be OK on my home machine. It was definitely showing up strangely on my work machine with a mixture of gravatars and geometric images. It was an XP machine, behind an evil firewall using FF3. Never seen this behaviour before. The gravatar.com site was showing as running very slowly. I'll be back on the work machine in 12 hours or so and I'll check if it's still doing it.

Comment: Gary, would it be possible for you to grab the URL used to request the image? (right-click, `Copy image Location` in Firefox) - it *should* be http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/232628cea0e6482f1afb285a92ebe6f7?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG for you, and if it is and you're still not seeing the right pic then it's either an issue with your firewall or Gravatar themselves. Bizarre...

Comment: Damn. Didn't see this comment until I'd left work. I'll postpone until I'm back in Monday.

Comment: @Mr.CRT Have updated OP. Probably a gravatar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravatar issue seems to be the cause of the problem